# Problem uploading multiple photos in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a project for a company, I need to add documents with a picture for each document
I have no problem adding texts, but I get errors when uploading images
Is any help very necessary?

This is the control code

```
$details_list = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->Identity_type); $i++) {

    $file_extension[$i] = $request -> file('Identity_image') -> getClientOriginalExtension();
    $file_name[$i] = time(). rand(1, 99) .'.'.$file_extension[$i];
    $path = 'images/Documentation';
    $request -> File('Identity_image[$i]') -> move($path,$file_name[$i]);

    $details_list[$i]['Identity_type'] = $request -> Identity_type[$i];
    $details_list[$i]['Document_number'] = $request -> Document_number[$i];
    $details_list[$i]['Country'] = $request -> Document_Country[$i];
    $details_list[$i]['Issue_date'] = $request -> Issue_date[$i];
    $details_list[$i]['Expiration_date'] = $request -> Expiration_date[$i];
    $details_list[$i]['Identity_image'] = $file_name[$i];
}

$Company -> DocumentationCompany() -> createMany($details_list);
```

I want to fix the problem when uploading pictures, or a better way to upload pictures than this method

Error
Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on array
Error
Call to a member function move() on null

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I saw that you are using $request->File() instead of using :

```
$request->file()
```

On line 7 of code that you've entered here.